# How do I auto scroll or auto pan using Plotly JS?

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

[image: Gif of plotting real time data]

I'm using plotly.js to plot real time data. I'm using the `extendTraces` method to do so. As can be seen, as new data comes in, the number of points on screen increases, and the graph condenses. I'd like to have the graph pan automatically to the right at a certain point (say 20 points). I was looking at the possible events for this in the documentation, it would seem `after_plot` would be my best bet though I don't know if `extendTraces` creates an `after_plot` event. Either way, is there a function to automatically pan the chart? I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: I don't know much about plotly, but I'd look into handling the scroll of the wrapping element natively. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not intuitive for me to find this so I can see why you had trouble finding the answer. But it appears that zoom and pan are controlled by the `range` attribute of one of the axes attributes. If you want to zoom or pan on the x axis, you need to change the `range` attribute on the `xaxis` attribute of the `layout`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).